# Difference between an affine transform and isomorphic transform in GF(2)?

Tags: finite-fields, cryptography

I asked this at [crypto.se](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55212/difference-between-an-affine-transform-and-isomorphic-transform-in-gf2) months ago, but never got any feedback.

What I am actually looking for is a bit of nuance.  In cryptography, and AES specifically, isomorphic transforms and affine transforms are used in hardware implementations.  The affine transform is used to assist with non-linearity and masking, whereas the isomorphisms are generally used to transform some bytes into a format that is easier for a hardware implementation.  You do an isomorphism, some squaring math and then an inverse isomorphism.  In both cases, if you do the affine followed by the inverse, and then the isomorphism followed by the inverse, you will get the same data you put in as an input. My question is:

What are the mathematical assumptions I should make when "affine" is used in a paper when compared to an "isomorphism"? As far as I can tell, in the context of GF(2), they are the same thing.

**Addendum:**
The origin of this question is that I wrote an [AES S-Box hardware implementation guide](https://github.com/bpdegnan/aes/blob/master/aes-sbox/documentation/aessbox.pdf).  It wrote it in the notation of [Vincent Rijmen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent_Rijmen), whose work became [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) with Joan Daemen because I am not a cryptographer and did not want to make any assumptions of language.  In my AES document, the to specific items are the Affine definition:
\begin{align}
\label{eqn:aff}
Af(a) = \left(
 \begin{array}{@{\hskip2pt}c@{\hskip2pt}@{\hskip2pt}c@{\hskip2pt}@{\hskip2pt}c@{\hskip2pt}@{\hskip2pt}c@{\hskip2pt}@{\hskip2pt}c@{\hskip2pt}@{\hskip2pt}c@{\hskip2pt}@{\hskip2pt}c@{\hskip2pt}@{\hskip2pt}c@{\hskip2pt}}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
 \end{array}
 \right)
 \times
 \begin{pmatrix}
  a_7 \\
  a_6 \\
  a_5 \\
  a_4 \\
  a_3 \\
  a_2 \\
  a_1 \\
  a_0 
 \end{pmatrix}
 \oplus
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  1 \\
  1 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
  1 \\
  1 
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
and then the isomorphism definition:
\begin{equation}
\label{matrix:isomorph}
\delta \times i =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \times
 \begin{pmatrix}
  i_7 \\
  i_6 \\
  i_5 \\
  i_4 \\
  i_3 \\
  i_2 \\
  i_1 \\
  i_0 
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Ultimately, they both become XOR logic circuits. As far as I can tell, when you push through on pen and paper, they are the affine and the isomorphism are structurally the same thing.

Comment: "Isomorphism" is a word used to denote a map that respects the structure at hand whatever it is, and is bijective (i.e. does not lose any data, i.e. is invertible), with the inverse also respecting the structure. Even though the term "Galois field" is used in cryptography, this has little to do with what mathematicians call Galois theory.

Comment: It seems that both terms denote the same kind of operations mathematically speaking, you only use different terminology to emphasize different purposes.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I can believe that to be true.  I was hoping there was some mathematical nuance that would guide assumptions.  It's just unusual to have different names for things that are so similar.  I could probably argue that the affine transform is a special case of the isomorphism.